# Delphi: how to change controls parent in delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll

I was create a 2 different dll and they have different controls drived from TCustomPanel but this 2 controls has a same interface and this interface own a setparent procedure !

this is the question : When I create that controls from dll, I have to set Parent of controls Form1 object first (No problem from here!), When I want to change parent of control (from the dll), the application can set the parent but I cannot see the child control anymore :(

I checked the position of child control in new Parent (Left and Top and Width and Height) no problem.
I checked the parent object classname, no problem too (he show me the new parent control classname)

I checked to child controls and controlcount of new parent control, everything is well

but I cannot see the control on the screen after trying to change parent!

Note: this 2 controls (child and parent) coming from different dlls

Thanks for your help

code

```
PIMediaComponent = ^IMediaComponent;
  PIPluginList    = ^IPluginList;
  IMediaComponent = interface
    ['{59C0BBCE-3185-4DF5-B8F2-9DAC8324D092}']
    function Invoke(method: PAnsiChar; p: array of TValue): TValue;
    function getObjectName(): PAnsiChar;
    function getObjectID(): integer;
    function getControl(): TWinControl;
    procedure setObjectID(id: integer);
    procedure setPositions(X,Y,W,H : integer);
    procedure assign_media(__file: PDataItem);
    procedure assing_events(__name: PAnsiChar; var event: pointer);
    procedure playmedia();
    procedure stopmedia();
    procedure setParent(p: TWinControl);
    procedure remove;
  End;

  IPluginList = interface
    ['{2CE6855D-165D-4381-9784-DAFEC9A7BBA9}']
    procedure RemovePlugin(PluginName: PAnsiChar);
    function ExecutePlugin(PluginName: PAnsiChar): Boolean;
    function getObject(ObjectName: PAnsiChar; ObjectID: integer = 0): IMediaComponent;
  end;
```

Class object in Child control dll

```
TVLCVideo = class(TVLCBase, IMediaComponent)
  private
    FObjectID     : integer;
    file_info     : PDataItem;
    FOnFinished   : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnStarted    : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure OnFinishProc(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnStartProc(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    function Invoke(method: PAnsiChar; p: array of TValue): TValue;
    procedure assign_media(__file: PDataItem);
    procedure assing_events(__name: PAnsiChar; var event: pointer);
    procedure playmedia();
    procedure stopmedia();
    procedure setParent(p: TWinControl);
    function getObjectName(): PAnsiChar;
    function getObjectID(): integer;
    procedure setObjectID(id: integer);
    procedure setPositions(X,Y,W,H : integer);
    function getControl(): TWinControl;
    procedure remove;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnFinished: TNotifyEvent read FOnFinished write FOnFinished;
    property OnStarted: TNotifyEvent read FOnStarted write FOnStarted;
  end;

procedure TVLCVideo.setParent(p: TWinControl);
var
  sName : string;
  vIntf: IMediaComponent;
  vParams: array[0..0] of TValue;
begin
  //  Self.ParentWindow := p.Handle;
    Self.Parent := p;
    Self.FParentWindow   := p.Handle;

    if Supports(Self.Parent, IMediaComponent, vIntf) then
    begin
      sName := pchar(getObjectName());
      vParams[0] := TValue.FromVariant(sName);
      vIntf.Invoke('GetActiveComponent', vParams);
    end;
end;
```

I just trying this in main form : I added a TButton and TPanel on the form and then ran the program. When I click the button, it can changes the TVLCVideo object parent, but I can not see the object on the screen :(

Button and Panel1 is not a runtime component, I've added them to the form at design time!

this is button onclick event :

```
Procedure TControllerMain.BtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Plugins.getObject('VIDEOPLAYER',0).setParent(view.Panel1);
    Plugins.getObject('VIDEOPLAYER',0).setPositions(0,0, 200, 200);
end;
```

I have not receive any error message from compiler or runtime. I just cannot see the TVLCVideo control after changing the parent :(

And I am using Delphi 2010

Comment: Why are you using DLLs instead of packages?

Comment: Because every control like a module of main application. Main application is empty don't have any control on the form. He need to create everything runtime from modules. Maybe I can write a new module in the future(like as plugin)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's really hard to answer a question where you've not provided any code and your description is not very clear. Please remember that we have no information about your problem other than what you tell us, and that we can't see your screen or code from here. The only thing we have to work with is the question you ask; if you don't provide clear details (or at least a clear description of the problem and some code to read), it's very hard to help you solve your problem. :)

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your reply. Can you check it again ?

Comment: Again, I'll ask: why are you using DLLs instead of packages? When you're using DLLs, each DLL has its own copy of the TWinControl class (and everything else, all the way down to TObject), so some things won't work together very well. If you use packages, you get the same modularity, but everything uses the same TWinControl class, so typecasting works properly. Module loading is what packages were *designed* for. If you don't use them, you will have weird problems. I can't tell whether the weird problems you *are* having are because you're not using packages, but they very well could be.

Comment: You've got more than one instance of the VCL. That doesn't work. Use packages or write a complete plugin API that keeps the VCL count to 1.